# Streaming Webcam using VLC +FFmpeg over lan - Error: cannot pre fill buffer

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, vlc

I've been trying to stream my webcam over lan using VLC and FFmpeg

but I end up with the error "Main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer"

Here is the code I've tried

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1680x1050 -r 30 -i :0.0+0,0 -vf "movie=/dev/video0:f=video4linux2, scale=180:-1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [movie]; [in] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, [movie] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -s 1280x768 -acodec libfaac -threads 0 -f mpegts - | vlc -I dummy - --sout '#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=thalha:3030}'
```

And this is the output

```
VLC media player 1.1.9 The Luggage (revision exported)
FFmpeg version 0.6.6-4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:28:21 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil   configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-1ubuntu1+medibuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavcodec  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavformat configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavdevice configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavfilter configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libswscale  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libpostproc configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[x11grab @ 0x98e8420]device: :0.0+0,0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1680 height: 1050
[x11grab @ 0x98e8420]shared memory extension  found
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 (X_ShmGetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
Warning: call to srand(1352225865)
Warning: call to rand()
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x9782aec] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x987258c] main access out: creating httpd
[0x98d0764] main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something by using v4l2 module and transcode module.

```
vlc v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=1680 :v4l2-height=1050 :v4l2-fps=30 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{preset=ultrafast},vb=512,fps=15,width=1280,height=768}:std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:3030}
```

[VLC v4l2 Module](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aModules/v4l2)